# ngCordova - How to remove all files from local dir

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I'm developing an app in Ionic Framework and I use ngCordova's file plugin to get access to the device’s files and directories.

I need to clean all files from a directory but I don't know how. In the official docs (http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/) tells how to remove a single file (*removeFile*)or how to remove all files and also the directory (*removeRecursively*) but I just need to only remove all the files from a dir.

I've tried to do this but it does not remove any file:

```
$scope.cleanFiles = function cleanFiles() {
    $cordovaFile.removeFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, "*")
      .then(function (success) {
        console.log('removed all files');
      }, function (error) {
        console.log('error removing files');
      });
  }
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to remove the directory? Couldn't you just remove the directory with its content and then create a new directory with the same name?

Comment: Is there any errors thrown?

Comment: FileError {code: 1, message: "NOT_FOUND_ERR"}

But I do have files in that directory...

Comment: There is also removeRecursively

Answer (score 1):

I am using the same plugin for files. it's working properly for me. please try to see logs when removing file. and other thing i noticed, you need not to write function like this.

```
$scope.cleanFiles = function cleanFiles()
```

rather

```
$scope.cleanFiles = function()
```

is enough for declaring it as a function.

Comment: Are you removing all files from a directory? If so, could you paste your code?? Thanks!!

Comment: I think I finally solved my problem! 
I've created another directory inside dataDirectory and I used the removeRecursively function.

Comment: could u check this @ni3aj